# Approach for a bimanual robot ROS controller? Impedance control

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, ros-control, controller-manager, ros-controllers

I'm working in a Cartesian impedance controller based in ros_control. So far I managed to programme a controller and load it in a panda robot and it works. Now I wonder about the approach in order to control two robots at the same time as my idea is to manipulate objects using a cartesian impedance control so I dont know how should I approach in order create a functional controller for my robots (a panda and a iiwa14). Also, I did a extensive search in internet but I didnt found any Cartesian impedance controllers for two robots. Please I'm stuck, I appreciate any information you could give me!

1. Should I duplicate this controller and load one for each robot. Meaning to control them separately.
2. Should I create an unique controller to control both robots in the simulation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more information on your ROS distribution, it seems that you work with ROS 1?

Comment: Yes, sorry! For now I will try to do it in simulation as I dont have a physical setup. I work in ROS 1 noetic. So far I have a running simulation for one robot in gazebo

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the physical connection to your robots. You have to ensure that the commands are sent synchronously to your robots if they should collaborate. How do you interface them?

Comment: As I commented, I dont have a real setup so I'm focusing my efforts basically in simulation until my university assembles the station.

Comment: then you might be limited to your simulation environment, which you haven't shared with us. E.g. ask yourself, do you have to use a single interface for both robots in simulation?